# Getting null value if i use two variables in ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am calling Action Method in ajax call but when i use single varibale in `data:test`, value is coming but when i used `data: '{"testData":"' + test + '","feature":"' + test + '"}'` it is giving me null value for both the variable.
Below is the code for javascript

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@(Url.Action("UpdatePlanFeatVal", "SuperAdmin"))',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        //data: JSON.stringify({ testData: test, feature: test}),
        // data: '{"testData":"' + test + '","feature":"' + test + '"}',
        data:test,
        success: function (result) {  
        },
        error: function (err) { 
        }
    });
```

and action controller

```
public ActionResult UpdatePlanFeatVal(string testData, string feature)
{   
   var cmd = (object)null;
   testData = testData.Trim();
   feature = feature.Trim();

   using (StoredProcedureContext sc = new StoredProcedureContext())
   {            
        cmd = sc.EditPricing(testData, feature);         
   }

   return View("ManageSubscriptionPlan");
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong and also it is not redirecting to `ManageSubscriptionView` also.

Comment: `data: {testData: test, feature: test },`. And you making an ajax call so it will never redirect (the whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page

Comment: ok what about null values?

Comment: What do you mean _null values_?

Comment: Is `UpdatePlanFeatVal` is member of class inherited from `ApiController`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke null value in controller for `string testdata, string feature`
@AdnanUmer i am not geeting your point..`UpdatePlanFeatVal` is simply a action method in `SuperAdmin` contoller

Comment: I guess your Action should return a [JsonResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and not a View...

Comment: @Steve, That means the value of your javascript variable is `null` - just hard code in a few vales to test `data: {testData: 'abc', feature: 'def' }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke these value are coming but data: '{"testData":"' + test + '","feature":"' + test + '"}' giving me null...but i am getting value of `test` variable if i use `data:test` means `test` has some value

Comment: You cant use the code you have shown - you are trying to mimic stringifying the data (in which case you would also need to add the `contentType: 'json'` option - just use `data: {testData: 'abc', feature: 'def' }` (not quotes, not `+` symbol`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks mate as always.. was missing to use `contentType` and use the code of Pragnesh.

Comment: There is no need at all to use `JSON.stringify(obj),` and `contentType: "application/json",` :) Just `data: obj` and omitting the `contentType` option works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will help you to send information in object that value will able to receive to controller side.

```
    var obj = {
        "testData": "test",
        "feature": "test"
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@(Url.Action("UpdatePlanFeatVal", "SuperAdmin"))',
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) { alert(data.chardata); },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

Comment: it is not possible, I have tested this functions.can you please pass the static data like above example.

Comment: That means it is sure issue is not in client side. It may be issue in the controller side.

Comment: thanks mate for being sure of the code you have given. I have double check and found `contentType` was missing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdatePlanFeatVal", "SuperAdmin")',
    data: { testData: 'test', feature: 'test' },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {  
    },
    error: function (err) { 
    }
});
```

Comment: these value are coming but `data: '{"testData":"' + test + '","feature":"' + test + '"}'` giving me null...now dnt say there is null value in `test` because if i use single variable `data:test` value is coming.

Comment: if you have defined test value just use `data: { testData: test, feature: test },` instead of `data: '{"testData":"' + test + '","feature":"' + test + '"}'`, if `test` was `null` it will pass `null` to controller.